# Есть ли возможность заменить иконки в метках на google maps и yandex maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

всем доброго дня и крепкого здоровья! Вопрос не относится к картам которые разработчики вставляют на страницы сайтов. Если я правильно понимаю вот эти иконки в метках

[image: пример_карты]

проставляются автоматически исходя из того чем занимается конкретная организация (общепит, магазин, банк...) Но может быть существует возможность вставить в метку свою иконку? :)

ps: народные карты яндекса не интересуют

Comment: нашел из документации, надеюсь поможет:  
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Comment: использование svg пути качестве маркера  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom#maps_marker_symbol_custom-javascript

Comment: В Яндекс.Картах все иконки стандартные, даже у самого [Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCUy42HMSD). Изменить их нельзя.